# Composer - Install a package without saving it into composer.json

Tags: drupal, composer-php, drupal-8

I'm trying to create a composer.json that generates a ready-to-use Drupal 8 (based on the excellent [Drupal Project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project)). It works well, but I want to include a custom theme that'll be use as a base for any developer. This theme is call in the composer.json `"my-package/my-theme": "*"`, and is automatically include in the Drupal's theme folder. Perfect!

The problem is : when you make a change to this theme, if you run a `composer install` or `composer update`, all your changes get deleted. I understand that's a normal behavior of Composer.

So, is it possible to install a package without saving it into composer.json / composer.lock ?

- I tried to do a `composer remove my-package/my-theme --no-update`, but it removed my package only in composer.json and not composer.lock, which give the same result.
- Am I supposed to install my package, and then delete it manually from composer.json and composer.lock ?
- Am I missing a secret option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answered here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7061#issuecomment-362209264) by a Composer contributor :

> This is intentionally impossible as well, not a missing feature or
>   anything. The vendor folder is Composer's alone to meddle with.
>
> Fyi - Node's `npm` is not only able to install packages without saving
>   them, it's even default. And this is one of the main reasons many
>   people are now using `yarn` instead because it cannot not save, as it is
>   highly frustrating to discover while deploying to production that you
>   forgot to add `--save` to that one vital dependency. One of Composer's
>   main design goals is absolute [dev/prod parity](https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity) for dependencies.

I found [an alternative solution](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7061#issuecomment-362205727) for anyone having the same issue :

> For anyone wanting to achieve the same thing as me, I finally make a
>   custom script launched after install that :
>
> - Make a copy of the theme folder
> - Change any mention of the previous theme system name to the new one (filenames + directly into files)
> - Remove theme with composer remove command
> - And finally enable the new theme
>
> It works for me as the downloaded theme is just a base to start
>   development and not an actual theme that will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

If your theme is part of your installation profile, it should be present in the composer.json file. Your developer should only use that theme as a base theme and create a sub-theme. Within that sub-theme, the developer can overwrite CSS as well as template files and template functions.

Comment: It's not an ideal solution in my case, but it can works. I've seen also that I can't simply remove the package from composer.json, as Composer will remove it in the next `composer update`